# geometry modification by iterative ST_MinimumBoundingCircle use

Tags: postgis

ST_MinimumBoundingCircle returns the smallest circle polygon that can fully contain a geometry, but if you execute this function iteratively on a geometry, it increases more and more, whereas **the same geometry should be maintained**.
Here is an example where a circle is created using ST_buffer with quad_segs by default.
Then apply ST_MinimumBoundingCircle on it and then reapply on the same geometry.

As you can see, the area of the geometry starts to increase every time ST_MinimumBoundingCircle is applied.

```
with gen_circle as(
SELECT ST_Buffer(
ST_GeomFromText('POINT(100 90)'),50) as circle)
select postgis_liblwgeom_version(), 
st_area(ST_MinimumBoundingCircle(circle)),
st_area(ST_MinimumBoundingCircle(ST_MinimumBoundingCircle(circle))),
st_area(ST_MinimumBoundingCircle(ST_MinimumBoundingCircle(ST_MinimumBoundingCircle(circle)))) from gen_circle
```

[image]

I'm using the last postgis version

Comment: well, inconsistencies are to be expected. there is a note on the doc page concerning the accuracy of the polygonal *approximation*, that, naturally, decreases with each 'iteration' (approx. of an approx. of ...). equally, a buffer circle can never be a perfect circle, as for the dependency of segmentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As ThingamuBob said, this is due to the parameter for number of segments per quarter circle in [the ST_MinimumBoundingCircle function](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MinimumBoundingCircle.html). As an illustration, you can see the same behaviour with ST_Buffer and how close the area of a circle with radius 1 approaches PI, as you increase the segments.

```
WITH segs(x) AS (VALUES(1), (10), (100), (1000), (10000))                                          
SELECT 
    x, 
    ST_Area(ST_Buffer(ST_MakePoint(0,0), 1, x))/PI() 
 FROM segs;
```

which returns:

```
    1 | 0.636619772367581
   10 | 0.995892735243561
  100 | 0.999958877155665
 1000 | 0.999999588766537
10000 | 0.999999995887669
```

Returning to your example:

```
WTIH gen_circle as(
  SELECT ST_Buffer(
           ST_GeomFromText('POINT(100 90)'),50) as circle)
SELECT        
    ST_Area(ST_MinimumBoundingCircle(circle, 1000)),
    ST_Area(ST_MinimumBoundingCircle(ST_MinimumBoundingCircle(circle, 1000), 1000)),
    ST_Area(ST_MinimumBoundingCircle(ST_MinimumBoundingCircle(
           ST_MinimumBoundingCircle(circle, 1000), 1000), 1000)) 
FROM gen_circle;
```

now returns:

7853.98324888513 | 7853.98809361888 | 7853.99293835557

which is a lot closer to the same answer -- of course, 4000 segments is still only an approximation of a circle, albeit a very close one.